# Two almost identical queries returning different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting different results for the following two queries and I have no idea why. The only difference is one has an IN and one has an equals.

Before I go into the queries you should know that I found a better way to do it by moving the subquery into a common table expression, but this is still driving me crazy! I really want to know what caused the issue in the first place, I am asking out of curiosity

Here's the first query:

```
use [DB.90_39733]
Select distinct x.uniqproducer, cn.Firstname,cn.lastname,e.code,
ecn.FirstName, ecn.LastName, ecn.entid, x.uniqline 
from product x
join employ e on e.EmpID=x.uniqproducer
join contactname cn on cn.uniqentity=e.uniqentity 
join [ETL_GAWR92]..idlookupentity ide on ide.enttype='EM' 
                                                        and ide.UniqEntity=e.UniqEntity
left join [ETL_GAWR92]..EntConName ecn on ecn.entid=ide.empid 
                                      and ecn.opt='Y'
Where x.UniqProducer =(SELECT TOP 1 idl.UniqEntity
                               FROM [ETL_GAWR92]..IDLookupEntity idl
                               LEFT JOIN [ETL_GAWR92]..Employ e2 ON e2.ProdID = ''                 
                               WHERE idl.empID = e2.EmpID   AND
                                     idl.EntType     = 'EM')
```

And the second one:

```
use [DB.90_39733]
    Select distinct x.uniqproducer, cn.Firstname,cn.lastname,e.code,
    ecn.FirstName, ecn.LastName, ecn.entid, x.uniqline 
    from product x
    join employ e on e.EmpID=x.uniqproducer
    join contactname cn on cn.uniqentity=e.uniqentity 
    join [ETL_GAWR92]..idlookupentity ide on ide.enttype='EM' 
                                                            and ide.UniqEntity=e.UniqEntity
    left join [ETL_GAWR92]..EntConName ecn on ecn.entid=ide.empid 
                                          and ecn.opt='Y'
    Where x.UniqProducer IN (SELECT TOP 1 idl.UniqEntity
                                   FROM [ETL_GAWR92]..IDLookupEntity idl
                                   LEFT JOIN [ETL_GAWR92]..Employ e2 ON e2.ProdID = ''                 
                                   WHERE idl.empID = e2.EmpID   AND
                                         idl.EntType     = 'EM')
```

The first query returns 0 rows while the second query returns 2 rows.The only difference is x.UniqProducer = versus x.UniqProducer IN for the last where clause.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Probably because `SELECT TOP 1` doesn't guarantee that the same record will be returned each time.  An `ORDER BY` should help.

Comment: thanks Rick, that did the trick. I was confused because running the subquery by itself always returned the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT TOP 1` doesn't guarantee that the same record will be returned each time.
Add an ORDER BY to your select to make sure the same record is returned.

```
(SELECT TOP 1 idl.UniqEntity
                               FROM [ETL_GAWR92]..IDLookupEntity idl
                               LEFT JOIN [ETL_GAWR92]..Employ e2 ON e2.ProdID = ''                 
                               WHERE idl.empID = e2.EmpID   AND
                                     idl.EntType     = 'EM' ORDER BY idl.UniqEntity)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess (with strong emphasis on the word “guess”) that the reason is based on how `equals` and `in` are processed by the query engine. For `equals`, SQL knows it needs to do a comparison with a specific value, where for `in`, SQL knows it needs to build a subset, and find if the "outer" value is in that "inner" subset. Yes, the end results should be the same as there’s only 1 row returned by the subquery, but as @RickS pointed out, without any ordering there’s no guarantee of  which value ends up “on top” – and the (sub)query plan used to build the `in` - driven subquery might differ from that used by the `equals` pull.

A follow-up question: which is the correct dataset? When you analyze the actual data, should you have gotten zero, two, or a different number of rows?